# Can this regex be made memory efficient

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I get an xml as plain unformatted text blob. I have to make some replacements and I use regex find and replace. 
For example:

```
<MeasureValue><Text value="StartCalibration" /></MeasureValue>
```

has to be converted to

```
<MeasureValue type="Text" value="StartCalibration"/>
```

The regex I wrote was

```
<MeasureValue><((\w*)\s+value="(.*?)".*?)></MeasureValue>
```

And the replacement part was:

```
<MeasureValue type="$2" value="$3"/>
```

Here a [link](http://regexr.com/53hob) showing the same.

The issue is that in a file having 370 such occurrences, I get out of memory error. I have heard of the so called greedy regex patterns and wondering if this can be the case plaguing me. If this is already memory efficient then I will leave it as it is and try to increase the server memory. I have to process thousands of such documents.

EDIT: This is part of script for Logstash from Elasticsearch. As per documentation, Elasticsearch uses Apache Lucene internally to parse regular expressions. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: In what language are you implementing this regex?

Comment: This is part of script for Logstash from Elasticsearch. As per documentation, Elasticsearch uses Apache Lucene internally to parse regular expressions. Not sure if that helps. I will keep looking and add more concrete info if I find it.

Comment: While the pattern could be improved (you can make the pattern fail faster by using negative character sets instead of repeating lazily), I don't think it would cause catastrophic backtracking or anything like that, it's not *terribly* inefficient. But, better to use an XML parser instead of a regex in these sorts of situations

Comment: NotYetAgain, when asked for clarification, as @Certain has, it's best to respond by editing the question (and adding tags, if appropriate, as here), rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained and readers should not be expected to read all comments in order to understand the question.

Comment: You should be using an xml package to iterate through your tags and build a new tree and minimize any regex application to small substrings within the text attributes. Also make sure you're not holding references to any objects you only need for a brief period..  for instance, stacking up xml trees in a list...

Comment: Applying regex to html/xml can make some people lose their mind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7915759

Comment: @Todd that one is a classic. A gem in the annals of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, specificity is positively correlated with efficiency in regex.
So, **know your data** and build something to surgically match it.

The more specific you build your regex, like literally writing down the pattern (and usually ending up with a freak regex), the fewer resources it will take due to the fewer "possibilities" it can match in your data.

To be more precise, imagine we are trying to match a string

```
2014-08-26 app[web.1]: 50.0.134.125
```

Approaches such as

```
(.*) (.*) (.*)
```

leaves it too open and prone to match with MANY different patterns and combinations, and thus takes a LOT more to process its infinite possibilities. check here https://regex101.com/r/GvmPOC/1

On the other han you could spend a little more time building a more elaborated expression such as:

```
^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} app\[[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\]\: [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$`
```

and I agree, it is horrible but much more precise. It won't waste your precious resources finding unnecessary stuff. check here https://regex101.com/r/quz7fo/1

Another thing to have in mind is: operators such as `*` or `+` do a scan operation, which depending on the size of your string, might take some time. Also, whenever is possible, specifying the anchors `^$` also help the script not to try to find too many matches within the same string.

---

Bringing it to your reality...

> If we have to use regex.

The million-dollar question is, how can we turn your regex into something more precise?

Since **there is no limit to tag name lengths** in XML... there is no way to make it utterly specific :(

- We could try to specify what characters to match and avoid `.` and `\w`. So substitute it to something more like `a-zA-Z` is preferrable. Also making use of negative classes `[^]` would help to narrow down the range of possibilities.
- Avoiding `*` and `?` and try to put a quantifier `{}` (although I don't know your data to make this decision). And as I stated above, there is no limit in XML for this.
- I didn't understand precisely the function of the `?` in your code, so removing it is something less to process.

Ended up with something like

```
<(([a-zA-Z]+) value="([^"]*)"[^<>]*)>
```

Not many changes though. You can try to measure it to see if there was any improvement.

But perhaps the best approach is **not to use regex** at all :(
I don't know the language you are working with, but if it is getting complicated with the processing time, I would suggest you to not use regex and try some alternative.

If there is a slight possibility to use a **xml parser** it would be preferable.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions

*Sorry if it wasn't as conclusive as you might have expected, but the field for working on it is likewise really open.*

Comment: Thanks for the replying. I will try to come up with a more precise targeted regex. Will keep option of throwing more memory at it for the last.